# what could be resulting in the errors

Tags: java, android

In navigation.java, errors:navigation is already defined in the 
 compilation unit and cannot find symbol method 
 `findNavController(Navigation ,int)`

**Navigation.java**

```
package com.example.bcuilders;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import android.view.View;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.Menu;

public class Navigation extends AppCompatActivity {

private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
            R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
}
```

and in the mainActivity.java error:cannot find symbol class intent
mainActivity.java

```
 package com.example.bcuilders;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void buttonClick(View view)
    {

        EditText et1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MyEmail);
        EditText et2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MyPass);

        String email=et1.getText().toString();
        String pass=et2.getText().toString();

        String oemail="admin";
        String opass="admin";

        if (email.equals(oemail) && pass.equals(opass)){

            Intent intent = new intent(this, Navigation.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
        else{
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid Email/Pass",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }



    }
}
```

errors:navigation is already defined in the compilation unit and cannot find symbol method findNavController(Navigation ,int)  in Navigation.java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a "Cannot find symbol" or "Cannot resolve symbol" error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-or-cannot-resolve-symbol-error-mean)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

1)  In the mainActivity.java error:cannot find symbol class intent mainActivity.java

Instead of this

```
Intent intent = new intent(this, Navigation.class);
```

Use this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Navigation.class);
```

Because you are using lowercase intent it is throwing that error.

2) In navigation.java, errors:navigation is already defined in the compilation unit and cannot find symbol method findNavController(Navigation ,int)

To solve this error rename your `navigation.java` to something else other than navigation. In your case it tries to find `findNavController(Navigation, int)` in your `navigation.java` class, which is not there.

Hope it solves your errors!!!